# Is "omni" a prefix or a root word?

Tags: prefixes, roots

I always thought it was a prefix, but then doing a google search confused me. I need to explain why a word like "omnipotent" is often mispronounced. If "omni" is a root word, it would be easy to conclude... If it is a prefix, i guess it's an exception to the rule?

Comment: Could you elaborate? How is being a root or prefix related to the pronunciation, and so on? IOW, please develop your reasoning a bit.

Comment: And how is _omnipotent_ often mispronounced?

Comment: I'll try... Stress would normally be out on the first syllable of a word - with or without prefixes. But with om-ni-po-tent, it is on the second. In some cases of prefixes, the stress would be on the second syllable or after the prefix. Certain bisyllabic words have their own rules, but I do not know which of all these "omni" fits into. I think that maybe it is treated as a prefix and therefore people put the stress on the "po" of "potent".

Comment: Om-nee–po-tent instead of omnippotent... You must have heard this before?

Comment: Compare how you might pronounce _omnivore_ and _omnivorous_

Comment: I usually see stress described as being on the n-th syllable _from the end of the word_, not from the beginning. The penultimate and pre-penultimate syllables are often stressed. Look at the word _penultimate_ itself, for example. I am with Drew in wondering what being a root or being a prefix has to do with the pronunciation. In [omnibus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/omnibus) the stress is at the pre-penultimate syllable, just like in omnipotent.

Comment: That makes it so much clearer. I went off what was explained in a text book. It clearly confused me even more. The prefix/root argument only made sense until I had to explain it to someone else. Thanks for helping oerkelens.

Answer (score 1):

The question of what is a prefix and what is a root is one which does not always admit of a clear answer. But in any case, the answer to the question has little bearing on the stress.

*Photo-* is probably a root, but it is stressed in *'photograph*, the link is stressed in *phot'ography*, and the second element is stressed in *photo'graphic*.

On the other hand *ambi-* seems more likely to be regarded as a prefix, but *am'bivalent* has stress on the second syllable, and *ambi'dextrous* on the third.

Even if we consider more clear-cut cases, the prefix *ex-* is often unstressed, but it is stressed in *'exquisite*, and in the noun *'extract* (but not the verb *ex'tract*).

Comment: I wouldn’t be surprised if there weren’t more speakers who stress the second syllable in *exquisite* than who stress the first.